# Realm release build with proguard fails - Could not find io.realm.RealmHelper

Tags: realm

We're getting ready to release our first app with realm and, *oops*, finally tried a release build. Everything works fine until we enable proguard, then the app crashes on launch with:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.activities.IntroActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.RealmHelper$ManifestModuleMediator
...
   Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.RealmHelper$ManifestModuleMediator
      at io.realm.y.a(Unknown Source)
      at io.realm.y.a(Unknown Source)
      at io.realm.y.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at io.realm.y.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at io.realm.z.a(Unknown Source)
      at com.example.realm.RealmHelper.a(Unknown Source)
      at com.example.activities.IntroActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)`

We're using the realm recommended proguard settings, i.e.:

`-keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
-keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
-keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
-keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class * { *; }
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn io.realm.**`

Any suggestions? Unfortunately we don't have any proguard wizards...

FWIW, I tried adding this line to the proguard config:

`-keep class io.realm.** { *; }`

That changed the trace to:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.activities.IntroActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.RealmHelper$ManifestModuleMediator
   ...
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.RealmHelper$ManifestModuleMediator
      at io.realm.RealmConfiguration.getModuleMediator(Unknown Source)
      at io.realm.RealmConfiguration.createSchemaMediator(Unknown Source)
      at io.realm.RealmConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at io.realm.RealmConfiguration.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at io.realm.RealmConfiguration$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
      at com.example.realm.RealmHelper.a(Unknown Source)
      at com.example.activities.IntroActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)`

Not sure if that helps...

Comment: What version of Realm are you using?

Comment: Also it sounds like perhaps the annotation processor isn't running. If you look at the Gradle output, do you see lines that look something like this: `note: Processing XXX`. If those are not present it means the annotation processor isn't running.

Comment: Realm 0.88.2. Indeed the annotation processor wasn't always running, but I'm not sure if that was just optimization because I wasn't always doing "clean" first or something else. FYI, we made it work with the answer I gave below. However, perhaps that's a coincidence? Feel free to edit, replace, add another, and I'll mark that as correct. I suspect there's a bigger issue here that I'm just clueless about :)  Thanks for the quick response!  Realm rocks!!

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix this by splitting out our two @RealmModule classes into separate files. I.e. we went **from**:

*RealmHelper.java*

```
@RealmModule(classes = {Publisher.class, Puzzle.class, Volume.class, VolumeSet.class})
public static class ManifestModule {
}

@RealmModule(classes = {PuzzleMove.class, PuzzleState.class, VolumeState.class})
public static class PuzzleStateModule {
}
```

**to**:

*realm/modules/ManifestModule.java*

```
@RealmModule(classes = {Publisher.class, Puzzle.class, Volume.class, VolumeSet.class})
public class ManifestModule {
}
```

and *realm/modules/PuzzleStateModule.java*

```
@RealmModule(classes = {PuzzleMove.class, PuzzleState.class, VolumeState.class})
public class PuzzleStateModule {
}
```

*RealmHelper.java*

```
import com.example.realm.modules.ManifestModule;
import com.example.realm.modules.PuzzleStateModule
```

I'm not sure what magic wasn't happening with one file that worked ok with two, and why Proguard nudged it one way or the other, but it seems to be working again!